# SQL select by relevancy - many to many

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this database structure:

```
product: id, name
type: id, name
product_type: id, product_id, type_id
```

Assuming that I have a product which has types with id's: 3, 5, 8, I want to select all others products that have types with id's: 3, 5, 8. If there doesn't exists any product with type 3, 5, 8, it should search for: (3, 5); (3, 8); (5, 8);

I'm using SQLite as db layer.

Thank you

Comment: I don't have any ideea. I've been thinking to make a sub-query to ... ORDER BY (subquery), for ordering, in this subquery I can select all other products that have id's: 3, 5, 8 - but I don't know how to select those products that have only 3, 5; or 5, 8...

Comment: Do you want to get only one product that is closest to the initial product.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want..

Comment: What do you mean "Assuming that I have a product which has types with id's:  3, 5, 8"?  Either you do or you don't.  Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: if the product X has the types with id's: 3, 5, 8 (many-to-many), I want to select all other products that has types id's: 3, 5, 8. If there isn't any such product, then select those products that has only 3, 5 or 5, 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this should work too.

```
SELECT
    p.name
FROM product p 
    JOIN product_type pt ON p.id = pt.product_id
WHERE pt.typeid IN (3, 5, 8) /*You can use a sub query to select the types*/
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY COUNT(pt.type_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the three types, then you can do:

```
select pt.product_id
from product_type pt
where product_id <> MYPRODUCTID
order by ((case when type_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when type_id = 5 then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when type_id = 8 then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc
limit 1;
```

If you don't, you can count the matches:

```
select pt.product_id
from product_type pt join
     product_type psone
     on pt.type_id = ptone.type_id and
        ptone.product_id = MYPRODUCTID and
        pt.product_id <> MYPRODUCTID
group by pt.product_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```